# Deployment Error for LWC INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have removed most of the permisisons on my profile and trying to deploy LWC using sfdx[image] Every LWC is failed.

Can anyone advise what permission on profile I should give to deploy LWC? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give "Customize Application" permission on your profile and then deploy.